# AJAX connect to PHP OOP WebService

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, call

Why does this not work?

```
class WebService {
    public static function CheckUserLogin() {
    }
}
```

How i can call this function?

My login.php Form

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" onsubmit="" action="">

E-Mail: <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" >
Passwort: <input type="text" size="30" name="passwort" id="passwort" >

<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />

</form>
```

login.js

```
 $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var passwort = document.getElementById('passwort').value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.php",
            data: "{ 'email': '" + email + "', passwort: '" + passwort + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

I want to Call the Function CheckUserLogin(). How i can do this? Or what i must do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your PHP file actually named `WebService.php`? Also are you using some sort of framework?

Comment: `CheckUserLogin` needs to return a JSON response - at the moment it does not return anything. Then, as per answers below, you can `echo json_encode()` that function's results in a file called "WebService.php".

Comment: Also, get into the habit of using your network monitor in your browser to watch AJAX requests live. This will greatly help you understand how they work, and why a particular case is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax call, alongwith the url you can send a parameter, say- action:

```
....
url: "WebService.php?action=checkLogin",
....
```

Then in PHP, just get this variable and call the desired function-

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){
   if($_GET['type'] == "checkLogin"){
      $ws = new WebService;
      echo $ws->CheckUserLogin(); 
      // this will call the desired function and the result will be obtained by the ajax
   }
}
```

Similarly you can use the same concept to call different functions at different points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class WebService.  The call to the file is just running the file procedurally.

```
$webservice = new WebService;
$webservice->CheckUserLogin();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check POST data in webservice.php like this

```
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['passport'])){}
```

and call your method if condition true like this

```
$a = new WebService;
$a->CheckUserLogin();
```

Success!)